# How to save Bitmap image into internal storage of Phone

Tags: java, android, cs50

When I start the app after loading image and editing when I click on save option app stops working and in Logcat it shows that I am having some error in MediaStore This app is having only main activity and it is used to apply a filter on photos and then save them filtered photos are bitmap files and then while saving photo it is converted to jpg format. Thanks!

```
package edu.harvard.cs50.fiftygram;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.Transformation;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import jp.wasabeef.glide.transformations.gpu.SepiaFilterTransformation;
import jp.wasabeef.glide.transformations.gpu.SketchFilterTransformation;
import jp.wasabeef.glide.transformations.gpu.ToonFilterTransformation;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    @Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE} ,1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] Permission, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, Permission , grantResults);
    }

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap original;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    }

    public void apply(Transformation<Bitmap> filter) {
        if (original != null) {
            Glide
                    .with(this)
                    .load(original)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(filter))
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }

    public void applySepia(View view) {
        apply(new SepiaFilterTransformation());
    }

    public void applyToon(View view) {
        apply(new ToonFilterTransformation());
    }

    public void applySketch(View view) {
        apply(new SketchFilterTransformation());
    }

    public void choosePhoto(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    public void savePhoto(View view) {
        File mFile = new File("/sdcard/temp");
        try {
            String sav = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mFile.getPath(), "a1.jpg", "Drawing");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            try {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                        getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                original = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(original);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
    Process: edu.harvard.cs50.fiftygram, PID: 19644
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MIME type application/octet-stream cannot be inserted into content://media/external/images/media; expected MIME type under image/*
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:481)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1828)
        at android.provider.MediaStore.createPending(MediaStore.java:616)
        at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:1736)
        at edu.harvard.cs50.fiftygram.MainActivity.savePhoto(MainActivity.java:85)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MIME type application/octet-stream cannot be inserted into content://media/external/images/media; expected MIME type under image/*
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)`

Answer (score 0):

According to the log says

> MIME type application/octet-stream cannot be inserted into content

It seems that you need to save the image as a JPEG  (image/jpeg) or PNG or WEBP file into a specific path then notify the MediaStore as following.

```
Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ...);
```

Comment: what output Stream shall i use?

Comment: will you please elaborate your code actually i am fresh in java

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For helping i got answer

```
public void savePhoto(View view) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        if (bitmapDrawable != null) {
            modified = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Log.d("log as per ur choice ");
                    showMessageOKCancel("as per ur choice.");
                    return;
                }
                Log.d("as per ur choice");

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            } else
                createDirectoryAndSaveFile(modified, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        } else {
            Log.d("savePhoto", "bitmapDrawable is null.");
        }
    }
```